# Get and compare OpenSSH version in bash

Tags: bash, version, openssh

I am trying to compare the OpenSSH version to target v8.8 or higher
I found that I can fetch the OpenSSH version with

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | awk '{print $1;}'
```

That returns, for example:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1
```

But how can I isolate the major and minor version numbers to compare them?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract the parts of the version number.

Comment: This will get you your major release: `(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\.)`  |  This will get your your version of major release: `(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=p)` (assuming the "p" is always there ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, major version number (exclude fixed text OpenSSH_ then capture any number of digits)

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | sed 's/OpenSSH_\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

and minor version number (exclude fixed text OpenSSH_ then exclude any number of digits and a dot, then capture any number of digits)

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | sed 's/OpenSSH_[0-9]\+\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

every sub-version number you possibly want

> ```
> ssh -V 2>&1 | mawk NF=NF FS='[._, ]+' OFS='\f'
> ```

```
OpenSSH
       8
        6p1
           LibreSSL
                   3
                    3
                     6
```

if u really want the patch number isolated too:

> ```
> ssh -V 2>&1 | mawk 'sub("O\fen","Open",$!(NF=NF))^_'  FS='[._,p ]+' OFS='\f'
> ```

```
OpenSSH
       8
        6
         1
          LibreSSL
                  3
                   3
                    6
```

more vertically oriented :

> ```
>  ssh -V 2>&1 | mawk 'sub(/\tLib/,"Lib",$!(NF=NF))'  FS='[._, ]+' OFS='\f\r\t'
> ```

```
OpenSSH
    8
    6p1
LibreSSL
    3
    3
    6
```

instead of having to hard-code in the seps, if u want a more generic one, `FS='[^[:alnum:]]+'` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
vers=($(ssh -V |& awk -F'[_.]' '{ print $2 " " $3+0 }'))
echo major: ${vers[0]}
echo minor: ${vers[1]}
```

To get a combined version number:

```
vers=$(ssh -V |& awk -F'[_.]' '{ print $2 "." $3+0 }')
echo $vers # e.g. "1.2"
```